# Apache NiFi instance hangs on the "Computing FlowFile lineage..." window

Tags: apache-nifi, dataflow, data-lineage

My Apache NiFi instance just hangs on the "Computing FlowFile lineage..." for a specific flow. Others work, but it won't show the lineage for this specific flow for *any* data files. The only error message in the log is related to an error in one of the processors, but I can't see how that would affect the lineage, or stop the page from loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was related to two things...

1) I was using the older (but default) provenance repository, which didn't perform well, resulting in the lag in the UI. So I needed to change it...

```
#nifi.provenance.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.provenance.PersistentProvenanceRepository
nifi.provenance.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.provenance.WriteAheadProvenanceRepository
```

2) Fixing #1 exposed the second issue, which was that the EnforceOrder processor was generating hundreds of provenance events per file, because I was ordering on a timestamp, which had large gaps between the values. This is apparently not a proper use case for the EnforceOrder processor. So I'll have to remove it and find another way to do the ordering.